# How to apply a pipe for a data binding?

Tags: angular, data-binding, pipe

I need to apply a pipe to a data binding in Angular but it doesn't work. I had something like that before:

`[message]="enum.text"` and I want to apply a custom pipe instead of `enum.text`. And I did something like this:

```
[text]=" '' + ({{'button.noResult' | translate }})".
```

or

```
[text]="'({{'button.text' | translate }})'"
```

, but it doesn't work...

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: That isn't what pipes are for. Either modify the data in your TypeScript code or apply the pipe in the component you are binding into.

Comment: yes, i'm using ngx-translate

Comment: OK, that doesn't change the fact that this isn't what pipes are for. Pipes are for changing the way data is displayed, not changing the data itself. If you need to change the data first, you need to do so in your outer component. If not, you can apply your `translate` pipe in the template of your inner component. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Ok, I understand. But my button.noResult it is in a json file an somehow the project see all the objects from that json. And I cannot modify the component.. because the child component that receive the value for noRowsToShowMessage it is in another project. My project is link with that one and I cannot access or modify it.

Comment: If you have access to `button.noResult`, you can manipulate it in your TypeScript code. That is the approach you need.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Actually, I needed to do like this to work:

```
noRowsToShowMessage="(button.noResult| translate }})"
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, this should work:

`noRowsToShowMessage="({{'button.noResult' | translate }})"`